# Select from multiple tables with no relationship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Say we have 3 tables: Movie, Actor, Cinema, I want to be able to select/search all records that matches a given term.

Now I got this working by doing something like this:

```
var movies = context.Movies.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(term))
    .Select(x => Mapper.Map<SearchResult>(x));
var actors = context.Actors.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(term))
    .Select(x => Mapper.Map<SearchResult>(x));
var cinemas = context.Cinemas.Where(m => m.CompanyName.Contains(term))
    .Select(x => Mapper.Map<SearchResult>(x));

var all = movies.Concat(actors).Concat(cinemas);
```

The problem here is that it results in 3 queries against the database which is not very efficient.

Note this is just an example, I have more than 3 tables I want to search.

So any ideas on how I can select from multiple tables that doesn't have relationship?

Comment: It should not result in 3 queries, instead should be converted to `... UNION ... UNION` query (unless it's EF Core - there anything might happen)

Comment: It is indeed EF Core, I should have tagged it properly. Thanks for clearing that out @Evk

Comment: That possibly isn't even going to compile, because you can't concat different types.  The first query will return `IQueryable<Movie>`, the second will return `IQueryable<Actor>`, so the concat will throw an error, but if you could do that, it would likely result in a single query as Evk suggests.

Comment: You're right @RobertMcKee , I am doing a generic select for each entity and mapping the result to a common type before concatenating. Will update the question.

Comment: If you can't find a better solution in plain old SQL, EF won't magically find one for you... so, do you have any idea how you would improve your query in SQL? I think 3 queries are quite acceptable for 3 distinct tables... if you actually have performance issues, better check whether they originate from the query or from EF overhead. Then optimize the query (eg. `StartsWith` index search would be more efficient than a full `Contains`) or use a different access technology as needed.

Comment: Another thing... might be worth to use `AsNoTracking`, also make sure to iterate `all` only once, since you're not calling `ToList` anywhere and you don't want to re-query this to often.

Comment: What if you try Union instead of concat? Also, doesn't your mapper.map materialize whole query before it has chance to construct union?

Comment: @Evk you're right, my mapper is materializing so I will try to change this and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: To start with you can just write selects by hand to see if this solves a problem. Though as I remember automapper has support for mapping select expressions (but not the way you do it now).

Comment: In order to keep sources `IQueryable`, you should use AM `ProjectTo` method in place of `Select` + `Map`. Unfortunately with currently latest official EF Core release (1.1.2), the `Concat` and `Union` queries are still processed with client evaluation, i.e. with separate db queries as in your example.

Comment: What you're actually after here is called "Full-text search" , but afaik no version of EF has any support for that.